# replacing hashtags with anchor links in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want text within a textarea that has the hash # character to be replaced with an anchor link as they're typing.

eg. something #somethingelse somethingsomethingelse its actual code would be

something <a href="/tags/#somethingelse" class="hashtag">#somethingelse</a> somethingelse

but in the textarea, I'd only want #somethingelse to be highlighted as I don't want it to actually have anchor code, kinda like how twitter and fb does it.

how does it work?

```js
$('textarea').on("keyup", function() {
  var str = $(this).val();
  if (!str.match(/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?#([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/g)) {
    if (!str.match(/#([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)#/g)) {
      str = str.replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/g, '<a href="/tags/#$1" class="hashtag">#$1</a>');
        $('textarea').html(str)
      }
    }
});
```

```css
.hashtag {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this with a simple `<textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

I write it in javascript  :

Html :

```
<textarea id="textArea" onkeyup="changeHash()"></textarea>
```

Javascript :

```
var outputString="";

function changeHash(){
var getObject= document.getElementById('textArea');
outputString =getObject.value.toString();
var checkTheLastChar = outputString.slice(-1);
if(checkTheLastChar=="#"){
 outputString = outputString.substring(0, outputString.length - 1);
 outputString += "⚓"; //Change it with anything you want
}
getObject.value = "";
getObject.value = outputString; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/emilvr/q27xgshe/1/

Comment: but because it's rendering back into a textarea, an anchor link would show up as its html tags rather than a link

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have a div below a transparent text area and duplicate the text from the textarea into the div with the links appended. If you append the text for a html tag to a text area it won't render because anything in a textarea only renders as editable text.